# Synthesize Digital Filter with Arbitrary Frequency-Response

Tags: matlab, filter-design, python

[fdesign.arbmagnphase](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/fdesign.arbmagnphase.html) is a MATLAB built-in function that will create a filter that best fits the frequency-response that it is given.

I'd like to implement a similar function in Python. What algorithms are used to synthesize filters based on an arbitrary frequency response?

Comment: Try Greg Berchin's FLDS filter design

Comment: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10428/berchins-fdls-arbitrary-filter-design-algorithm?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For FIR filter design, common algorithms include Remez exchange or Parks-McClellan :
[What is the difference between Remez exchange and Parks-McClellan filter design?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/220/what-is-the-difference-between-remez-exchange-and-parks-mcclellan-filter-design)

For IIR filters, one possibility is the Differential Evolution algorithm, as described in some IEEE journals.  If you have a realistic desired phase response and can guess the filter order, then [Berchin's FDLS method](https://github.com/blair3sat/fdls) may be suitable.